# Grunt concurrent task outputting nothing

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I want my Grunt based setup to run both "test" (i.e. the unit tests) and "server" (i.e. the web server) at the same time, so that I can just do `grunt testAndServer` to run both (and update both when any file is changed) in the same terminal.

Code (much of it is based on the `yo angular` scaffold):

```
// in initConfig:
concurrent: {
  testAndWebServer: [
    'karma',
    'watch'
  ]
},
```

and later

```
grunt.registerTask('testAndServer', function (target) {
  if (target === 'dist') {
    return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
  }

  grunt.task.run([
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:server',
    'autoprefixer',
    'compass',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open',
    'concurrent:testAndWebServer'
  ]);
});
```

This actually works, but I don't get any output in the terminal (PowerShell) window. I would like the karma task to show the results of the tests. How can I acheive that?

I am running Node.js v0.10.20 on Windows 7, on a quadcore machine.

Comment: Curious, why do you need them to run concurrent?

Comment: @limelights Because I do not want to run test and server in separate cmd.exe terminals, I want them to run in the same terminal.

Comment: I just made a major edit: The tasks actually execute, and respond to file changes, however they don't output anything in the terminal window. Which is bad for the test task, since I want to see that output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just realized that I missed the `logConcurrentOutput` option.

This makes it work:

```
  testAndWebServer: {
    tasks: ['watch', 'karma'],
    options: { logConcurrentOutput: true }
  },
```